# Elif not executing in program

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a simple text-based game for a college course in which I need to be able to move between rooms until the exit criteria are met. The problem I am running into is I can't get the ELIF statement to work to set my location from the bedroom to the cellar. It keeps it as bedroom. I am not sure what I'm missing here.

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


location = 'Great Hall'
direction = ""


while direction != exit:
    print("\nYou are in the", location)

    possible_moves = rooms[location].keys()
    print("Possible moves:", *possible_moves)

    direction = input("Which direction do you wish to go? ").strip().capitalize()
    print("You entered:", direction)

    if direction in possible_moves:
        if location == 'Great Hall':
            location = 'Bedroom'

        if location == 'Bedroom':
            if direction == 'North':
                location = 'Great Hall'
            elif direction == 'East':
                location = 'Cellar'

        if location == 'Cellar':
            location = 'Bedroom'

    elif direction is not possible_moves:
        if direction == 'Exit':
            print("Thank you for playing the game.")
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid direction.')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting here, please [try to find the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by tracing through the logic of the code. For example, were you able to verify that the expected `location = 'Cellar'` line is reached? (For example, by using a debugger, or putting a `print` call in the same place to see if the print happens.) Were you able to check *what happens next* after that?

Comment: As an aside: for this assignment, you are **not intended** to try to use this `if`/`elif`/`else` logic to determine the next position. Instead: think carefully about the provided `rooms` data. Suppose the player is currently in the `'Bedroom'`. Look at the value located under `rooms['Bedroom']`: `{'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'}`. Do you see how this corresponds to the available movement options? Can you see how looking up the `direction` in this dictionary, would tell you the new value for the `location`?

Comment: Also: `elif direction is not possible_moves:` does not make logical sense. For one thing, of course `direction` and `possible_moves` will be different objects (and not even the same type); presumably you meant `direction not in possible_moves` (which means the same thing as `not (direction in possible_moves)`. However, none of this is necessary; we already checked `if direction in possible_moves:`, so we just need `else:` after that. (Do you understand why?)

Comment: @karlKnechtel Could you point me to what syntax/method would allow me to grab a value from the room dictionary so I could update my location? I spent the better part of the morning trying to do this vs the if/elif/else but I couldn't figure it out. I don't mind doing some research on it but I could not find a method that was talked over in my class

Comment: To be clear: the question is how to look a value up in a dictionary, given a key? You're certain you don't have anything in your course notes about this? Actually, no, I know for a fact that you already know how to do this, because you are already doing it in the code. Look closely at the line `possible_moves = rooms[location].keys()`. Think carefully about what the `rooms[location]` part means.

Comment: I understand how to look at a particular section of a dictionary, but how to grab that information and put it in a variable via the loop is where I was lost at. I feel like the answer is simple but I'm at a loss. Would a nested for loop work better?

Comment: ... Okay, so. `rooms[location]` is the dictionary you want. You have a variable named `direction`, which holds the key that you want to use, in order to get the value. The way that you look something up in a dictionary is to an expression for the dictionary, then `[`, then an expression for the key, then `]`. Yes? So, that looks like `rooms[location][direction]`, right? What happens when you try that? I don't understand where the sticking point is here. I especially don't understand why you are talking about loops, at all.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wrote it like rooms[location[[direction]] and realize how dumb this is now but at the time I ruled out this as an answer. Appreciate you taking the time and explaining this! love python/coding but brand spanking new to it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you change location from Bedroom to Cellar you straight away change it back again, `if location == 'Cellar'` matches, you need to change a couple of your ifs to elif

```
    if direction in possible_moves:
        if location == 'Great Hall':
            location = 'Bedroom'

        elif location == 'Bedroom': # if -> elif
            if direction == 'North':
                location = 'Great Hall'
            elif direction == 'East':
                location = 'Cellar'

        elif location == 'Cellar': # if -> elif
            location = 'Bedroom'
```

Comment: This, Thank you so much that explains it for me.

Answer (score 0):

the `elif` is asking whether or not direction is possible_moves, instead of is in possible moves.

Comment: This is correct, but does not address the problem OP was asking about.